# Java Array calculations not outputting properly?

Tags: java, arrays, output

I am currently working on a programming assignment and I need to use Arrays I inputted from a file and manipulate it to display the highest population difference as well as the lowest, both with the two years these happen. I managed to get the highest population difference and year correct, however I can't get the lowest to output the right years.

**I am supposed to be getting this as an output:**

Greatest increase is:  3,185 thousand for yr: 1954 to 1955

Smallest increase is:  1,881 thousand for yr: 1966 to 1967

**But I keep getting this:**

Greatest increase is:  3,185 thousand for yr: 1954 to 1955

Smallest increase is:  1,881 thousand for yr: 1952 to 1953

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class AssignmentOne
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    // Array Version
    ArrayVersion();
    System.out.println("Finished Array Version of Assignment\n");

}

// Method for ArrayVersion
public static void ArrayVersion() throws IOException
{
    // Year as variables
    int year = 1950;

    // Array to use for Population data
    int[] population =  new int[40];

    // Call the method to get data into array
    population = getDataFromFile("USPopulation.txt");

    if(population == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Population did not load");
        return;
    }

    //Processing Array Elements
    // Calculating the difference 


    // Output Titles
    System.out.println("This is the Simple Array Version of \nPopulation Data US");
    System.out.println("\nYear \tPopulation \tDifference");
    System.out.println("");

    // Output Year, Population, Difference
    System.out.printf("%d \t%,d,000\n", year, population[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < population.length; i++)
    {
    System.out.printf("%d \t%,d,000 \t%,d,000 \n", ++year, population[i], population[i] - population[i-1]);
    }

    // Calculating the average + displaying it
    double sum = 0;
    double difference = 0;
    double average;
    for(int index = 1; index < population.length; index++)
    {
        difference = population[index] - population[index-1];
        sum += difference;

    }

    average = sum / population.length * 1000;
    System.out.printf("Avg population difference is: %,12.1f thousand\n", average);


    // Greatest Population difference + output
    int highest = 0;
    int gtDiff = 0;
    int year1 = 1950;
    for(int k = 1; k < population.length; k++)
    {
        gtDiff = population[k] - population[k-1];

        while(gtDiff > highest)
        {
            year1 = year1 + 1;

            if(gtDiff > highest)
               highest = gtDiff;
        }



    }
    System.out.printf("Greatest increase is:  %,d thousand for yr: %d to %d\n",highest, year1 - 1, year1);

    // Lowest Population Difference + output
    int lowest = population[0];
    int lwDiff = 0;
    int year2 = 1950;
    for(int m = 1; m < population.length; m++)
    {
        lwDiff = population[m] - population[m-1];
        while(lwDiff < lowest)
        {
            year2 = year2 + 1;

            if(lwDiff <  lowest )
                lowest = lwDiff;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Smallest increase is:  %,d thousand for yr: %d to %d\n",lowest, year2 -1, year2);


}
// Method to get data from specified "filename" into an array of ints
public static int[] getDataFromFile(String USPopulation) throws IOException
{

    // Opening file
    File file = new File("C:/Users/cstuser/Documents/USPopulation.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);


     int fileSize = 0;
     while(inputFile.hasNext())
     {
         inputFile.nextInt();
         fileSize++; 
     }

     inputFile.close();
     // Now load the integer data into the array named fileData
     // This is your job

     Scanner input2 = new Scanner(file);
     int[] fileData = new int[fileSize];
     for(int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
     {
         fileData[i] = input2.nextInt();
     }

     input2.close();
     // return the array fileData
     return fileData;
}

}
```

If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, that would be great. Thank you!

EDIT: This is what the file contains

151868

153982

156393

158956

161884

165069

168088

171187

174149

177135

179979

..... continues

Comment: provide the input too....

Comment: It would be much better if you used debugger instead of this site.

Comment: I have tried using the debugger, it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Can you give a small sample of USPopulation.txt?

Comment: I can hardly believe that debugger does nothing. This is literally the most useful tool in any developer's arsenal.

Comment: Well my program doesn't detect any errors and nothing happens when I debug it

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you debug a program?

Comment: dude are you going to help me with my problem or not. I'm new to programming and I really don't have time for your sass.

Comment: ^ because that will help... :|

Comment: I'm genuenly trying to help, you know. "Give man a fish, and he'll not be hungry for a day. Teach man to fish, and he'll not be hungry for rest of his life".

Comment: if your trying to help me, then tell/explain to me what I am doing wrong. Because I am super confused and have no idea what it is I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you get what you did wrong? You were starting a while-loop inside your for-loop that ALWAYS did just 1 interaction because you changed the values of the variables inside the cycle. You added a year to the min/max year only when you found a value bigger/smaller (THIS was the error) you had to add the year of your interaction instead, cause you are going trough the array even if the difference was not smaller/bigger

Comment: ^ And all of that would've been obvious to you if you stepped through the problem code with debugger and saw it for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to change your code as follow (for the minus diff):

```
for(int m = 1; m < population.length; m++)
    {
        lwDiff = population[m] - population[m-1];
        if(lwDiff < lowest)
        {
            year2 = 1950 + m;
            lowest = lwDiff;
        }
    }
```

And to do the same changes to the max:

```
for(int k = 1; k < population.length; k++)
    {
        gtDiff = population[k] - population[k-1];

        if(gtDiff > highest)
        {
            year1 = 1950 + k;
            highest = gtDiff;
        }

    }
```